# simultaneous diagonalize

Tags: linear-algebra

$A = \begin{pmatrix}
18 & -9 \\ -9 & 9
\end{pmatrix}$
$B = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 \\ 2 & -2
 \end{pmatrix}$

1. Find a real invertible matrix such as $P^tAP = I_2$ and $P^tBP$ is diagonal matrix.
2. is there only one $P$ ?

I was trying to solve it like that, using a 
**matching** row & column operations on A, such as:
$R_2 \to R_2 + \frac{1}{2} R_1, C_2 \to C_2 + \frac{1}{2} C_1$ and so on until I get $P^tAP = I_2$.

and I get $P$ by making the same operations on $I_2$(only on the rows not the columns). is that the right way to solve it?

Comment: @Moo yeah it's the same from the book. why does it seems wrong?

Comment: @moo well it actually was in our final exam, but it's not in english.